# Graphing a tan wave with x and y co-ordinates in d3

Tags: javascript, math, svg, d3.js

When I created this [sine wave](https://cutting.scot/viz/sine2), I created the following d3 scales:

```
const xScale = scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, Math.PI * 2])
  .range([0, width]);

const yScale = scaleLinear()
  .domain([-1.0, 1.0])
  .range([height - 100, 0]);
```

I can then add numbers to an array that starts at 0 and increase by `(Math.PI * 2) / 360` on a timer that animates the sine wave.

```
const nextTime = sineData[sineData.length - 1] + (Math.PI * 2) / 360;

sineData.push(nextTime);
```

I then create a d3 `line` function for the sine wave:

```
const sineCurve = line<number>()
  .curve(curveMonotoneX)
  .x((d) => xScale(d))
  .y((d) => yScale(Math.sin(d) + 1));


<path d={sineCurve(state.sineData) />
```

I want to create a tan wave like this but I'm not sure how as the wave is not continuous and there are multiple at different points.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, if you're using D3 for plotting math functions, you're using the wrong tool. I wrote an explanation [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/171946/143592) and [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/202638/143592).

That said, the important thing here is realising that the tangents go from minus infinity to infinity, and that's clearly something that you don't want. So, what you can do is using the [`defined`](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#line_defined) method for skipping some values.

Here, I'm setting a maximum and minimum tangent value you want to plot in the y axis (named `maxTan`) in the line generator:

```
const lineGenerator = d3.line()
    .defined(d => Math.tan(d) < maxTan && Math.tan(d) > (-maxTan))
```

That way the chart will stop at the `maxTan` y value, and will resume from minus `maxTan` at the bottom, using a single `<path>`.

And here is a demo (using radians):

```js
const svg = d3.select("svg"),
  margin = 20,
  width = 500,
  height = 300,
  maxTan = 5,
  circles = 1;

const xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([-circles * Math.PI * 2, circles * Math.PI * 2])
  .range([margin, width - margin]);

const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([-maxTan, maxTan])
  .range([height - margin, margin]);

d3.axisBottom(xScale)(svg.append("g").attr("transform", `translate(0,${height/2})`));
d3.axisLeft(yScale)(svg.append("g").attr("transform", `translate(${width/2},0)`));

const data = d3.range(xScale.domain()[0], xScale.domain()[1], 0.025);

const lineGenerator = d3.line()
  .defined(d => Math.tan(d) < maxTan && Math.tan(d) > (-maxTan))
  .x(d => xScale(d))
  .y(d => yScale(Math.tan(d)));

const tan = svg.append("path")
  .attr("class", "tanPath")
  .datum(data)
  .attr("d", d => lineGenerator(d));
```

```css
.tanPath {
  fill: none;
  stroke: blue;
  stroke-width: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="300"></svg>
```

Comment: great answer, one more question: how to show x axis label with \pi style?

Comment: @lucky1928 you have to use `ticks()` and `tickFormat()`. It's better asking it as a separate question.